# using simple linked list insert function when we have more that one type of data

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
so this is my code i got so many errors
```

so basically i got an assignment when i have to create a function tht insert each time a computer with submitting all his full infos (id,marque,ram) , so first i made a info structure where i added all the information that the user should enter (int ram , int id , int marque ) then i declared a linked list

```
void insererP(pliste &tete) {
   int s,s1,a;
    if(tete==NULL)
    {
        tete=new liste;
        tete->suiv=NULL;
        cout<<"Veuillez saisir un id: ";
        cin>>s;
        cout<<"Veuillez saisir une marque : ";
        cin>>s1;    
        cout<<"Veuillez saisir un ram : ";
        cin>>a; 
        tete->info=new inf;
    
            tete->info->id=s;
        tete->info->marque=s1;
        tete->info->ram=a;
    
        
    }
    else
{           pliste *p=new pliste;
        cout<<"Veuillez saisir un id: ";
        cin>>s;
        cout<<"Veuillez saisir une marque : ";
        cin>>s1;    
        cout<<"Veuillez saisir un ram : ";
        cin>>a; 
    //  p->info=new pliste;
        
         
    
            tete->info->id=s;
        tete->info->marque=s1;
        tete->info->ram=a;
    
               // p->suiv =tete;
             //   tete=p;
        }}
```

Comment: You said *"I got so many errors"* but never included them in your question. And... the the code in the question isn't even remotely compilable for *us* to reproduce those same errors because there is no [mcve]. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn what a proper [mcve] is, and how to build one.

Answer (score 0):

The simple code to add a node

```
void insert(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();
 
    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;
 
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
 
    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

Now for your case, it will be

```
void insert(pliste** head_ref, pliste new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    pliste* new_node = new pliste();
     
    /* 2. Add data here */
    // .....

    /* 3. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;
 
    /* 4. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
 
    /* 5. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

Comment: What has probably eluded you is `pliste` is actually a pointer type to a `liste` already, hidden in an ill-advised typedef alias. I know, it's hard to tell, and that is precisely the reason why doing that is so ill-advised.